# Slidesjs doubles image

Tags: jquery, css, slideshow

I'm currently using SlidesJS for an image slideshow. When I request the webpage, the first slide is downloaded twice for some reason, which takes up some bandwith. I don't know why this is happening.... It has something to do with jquery.

[image: the image is requested twice]

Edit: It's also happening at this example (use F12 for code)[example](http://slidesjs.com/examples/standard/)

Comment: Its even harder for us to tell. How are we suppose to know without even seeing any code_

Comment: could you show some of your code?